# Bootstrap 2.x carousel slide and ui.bootstrap (angularjs) not working together

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I am really new to the web development, so looking for some help to understand how to get around the strange issue I am having with the Bootstrap and the AngularJS.

I have a carousel slide set up as show below which works (some free template I downloaded)

```
 <section id="carouselSection" style="text-align: center">
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" >
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div  style="text-align:center"  class="item active">
            <div class="wrapper"><img src="content/sarakutheme/themes/images/carousel/business_website_templates_1.jpg" alt="business webebsite template">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>What we do?</h2>
                <p>We specialise in web design, web development and graphic design for different Desktop, Mobiles and Tablets.  We recently introduce cheapest and best mobile web design packages in our services. </p>
                <a href="services.html" class="btn btn-large btn-success">Read more</a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div  style="text-align:center"  class="item">
            <div class="wrapper"><img src="content/sarakutheme/themes/images/carousel/business_website_templates_2.jpg" alt="business themes">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Who we are?</h2>
                <p>We specialise in web design, web development and graphic design for different Desktop, Mobiles and Tablets. We recently introduce cheapest and best mobile web design packages in our services.  </p>
                <a href="about_us.html" class="btn btn-large btn-success">Read more</a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div  style="text-align:center"  class="item">
            <div class="wrapper"><img src="content/sarakutheme/themes/images/carousel/business_website_templates_3.jpg" alt="business themes">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>What we have done?</h2>
                <p>We specialise in web design, web development and graphic design for different Desktop, Mobiles and Tablets.  We recently introduce cheapest and best mobile web design packages in our services.  </p>
                <a href="portfolio.html" class="btn btn-large btn-success">Our Portfolio</a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div  style="text-align:center"  class="item">
            <div class="wrapper"><img src="content/sarakutheme/themes/images/carousel/business_website_templates_4.jpg" alt="business themes">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Blog</h2>
                <p>We specialise in web design, web development and graphic design for different Desktop, Mobiles and Tablets. We recently introduce cheapest and best mobile web design packages in our services.  </p>
                <a href="blog.html" class="btn btn-large btn-success">Recent NEWS</a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div  style="text-align:center"  class="item">
            <div class="wrapper"><img src="content/sarakutheme/themes/images/carousel/business_website_templates_5.jpg" alt="business themes">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Need help?</h2>
                <p>We specialise in web design, web development and graphic design for different Desktop, Mobiles and Tablets.  We recently introduce cheapest and best mobile web design packages in our services.  </p>
                <a href="contact.html" class="btn btn-large btn-success">Contact us</a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

as long as my module is defined as

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

but the moment I add the "ui.bootstrap" to the module list, < & > the buttons on the carousel are messed up as its uppending some angularjs classes to that.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ["ui.bootstrap"]);
```

looks like the in ui.bootstrap there is also a carousel that is messing up my class for next and previous. I am wondering if some one has an workaround for this issue.

**Updated with Plunker Link** and some additional remarks

Link : http://plnkr.co/edit/HGana8kS9wyjUJcy4bQ9

if you notice in that, i have included app.js where the issue can be reproduced. just removing the "ui.bootstrap" makes the code work, and the reason I can think of is that in the chrome it shows that its adding a div across my (<) and (>)

```
<div ng-class="{
'active': leaving || (active &amp;&amp; !entering),
'prev': (next || active) &amp;&amp; direction=='prev',
'next': (next || active) &amp;&amp; direction=='next',
'right': direction=='prev',
'left': direction=='next'
```

}" `class="right carousel-control item" ng-transclude="" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="ng-scope">&gt;</span></div>`

Hope this helps to understand the issue better

Regards
Kiran

Comment: Can you post a plunkr?

Comment: Yup, hard to say more without a minimal reproduce scenario....

Comment: I have updated my post with additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the solution was lot simpler than I imagined, when there is a class "**ng-non-bindable**" applied to

```
<a class="right carousel-control ng-non-bindable" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
```

it stopped the additional div from being applied. it now works like a charm.